# How to prevent angular child component’s click event from getting triggered too early?

Tags: javascript, angular, event-handling, components

I was trying to create a search bar component that opens after clicking on a search icon in its parent component, and closes after clicking outside of the search bar. However, after clicking the opening icon it immediately triggered a (document:click) event in the search bar component, which was closing it too early as a result.

I found a workaround for this problem by creating a ‘searchMode’ variable in the search bar component and setting a timeout (in ngOnInit) that set it to true after 100ms. However, I’m wondering, if there’s any better solution to this problem rather than setting the timeout?

(Expected results:  user clicks the search icon in navigation component —> search bar component shows up in place of the search icon —> user clicks outside of the search bar component —> the search bar disappears and the search icon shows up again)

navigation.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navigation',
  templateUrl: './navigation.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navigation.component.scss'],
})
export class NavigationComponent implements OnInit {
  searchActive = false;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  openSearchBar(): void {
    this.searchActive = true;
  }

  closeSearchBar() {
    this.searchActive = false;
  }
}
```

navigation.component.html

```
<div class="weather-app__navigation">
  <ul class="weather-app__navigation-list">
    <li class="weather-app__navigation-list__item">
      <i class="fas fa-bars bars-icon"></i>
    </li>
    <li class="weather-app__navigation-list__item">
      <ng-container
        *ngIf="searchActive; then searchBarContent; else searchIcon"
      ></ng-container>
    </li>
    <ng-template #searchBarContent
      ><app-search-bar (closeSearch)="closeSearchBar()"></app-search-bar
    ></ng-template>
    <ng-template #searchIcon
      ><i class="fas fa-search search-icon" (click)="openSearchBar()"></i
    ></ng-template>
    <li class="weather-app__navigation-list__item">
      <i class="fas fa-info-circle about-icon"></i>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

search-bar.component.ts

```
import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
  ElementRef,
  ViewChild,
  Output,
  EventEmitter,
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-search-bar',
  templateUrl: './search-bar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search-bar.component.scss'],
  host: {
    '(document:click)': 'onClick($event)',
  },
})
export class SearchBarComponent implements OnInit {
  searchMode = false;
  city = '';
  @ViewChild('searchBar') searchBar!: ElementRef;
  @Output() closeSearch = new EventEmitter();

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.searchMode = true;
    }, 100);
  }

  onSubmit() {
    console.log('submitted');
  }

  onClick(event: Event) {
    if (!this.searchMode) {
      return;
    }

    if (!this.searchBar.nativeElement.contains(event.target)) {
      this.closeSearch.emit();
    }
  }
}
```

search-bar.component.html

```
<div class="weather-app__search-bar" #searchBar>
  <form class="weather-app__search-bar__form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <input type="text" name="city" [(ngModel)]="city" placeholder="City Name" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: try using `event.stopPropogation()` for the click event on the search button

Comment: @AyushSeth This solution works as well. Thanks!

Comment: glad to help, I've added it as an answer for other people's reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `event.stopPropogation()` on the click event captured on the search button, this will prevent the event from bubbling.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation